# mysql query will not run faster

Tags: php, mysql, indexing, query-optimization

This is my query

```
    SELECT `tbl_user`.`file_id` , `tbl_user`.`folder_id` , `tbl_user`.`user_id` , `tbl_user`.`fathername` , `tbl_user`.`investor_type` , `tbl_user`.`user_name` , `account_id` , `user_witness_id` , `visible` , sum( tbl_user_payment.user_amount ) AS amt, `tbl_user_payment`.`trans_type`
FROM (
`tbl_user`
)
LEFT JOIN `tbl_user_payment` ON `tbl_user`.`user_id` = `tbl_user_payment`.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_user_stamp` ON `tbl_user_stamp`.`user_id` = `tbl_user_payment`.`user_id`
WHERE `tbl_user`.`visible` = '1'
AND `tbl_user`.`user_name` LIKE '%1%'
OR `tbl_user`.`file_id` LIKE '%1%'
OR `tbl_user`.`folder_id` LIKE '%1%'
OR `tbl_user`.`fathername` LIKE '%1%'
OR `tbl_user`.`nic` LIKE '%1%'
OR `tbl_user`.`email` LIKE '%1%'
OR `tbl_user`.`city` LIKE '%1%'
OR `tbl_user`.`phone` LIKE '%1%'
OR `tbl_user`.`bank_account` LIKE '%1%'
GROUP BY `tbl_user`.`user_id`
```

i have indexed all the like values but still my query will take abuot 2 seconds, i dont know why it is doing that.

on my local system it take about 2 seconds first time and then it will take about 0.002 seconds after that

but on live server it will not go less than 2 seconds

Can some one plz help me

and the recods are about 1000 only in user table and user_stamp table and abuot 1200 in user_payment table

Thankx

Comment: Do you really need all that `LIKE` statements? Comparing with `=` would be much faster and could use the indixes.

Comment: did you also index the foreign keys?

Comment: using LIKE slows down your query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the query cache is not activated on your live server.

You want to check your MySQL live server configuration.

[Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html)

Answer (score 0):

That probably means that caching is turned on on your machine, and turned off on the live machine. Try doing different searches on your local machine, those should all be taking about the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can Create VIEW on MySQL to collect data from tables instead of using join and select only from the view , that will make your data shown more faster..

Learn more about view [Click Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using LIKE this way will not use indexes. To make use of indexes, you must search from the begginning of the string ('1%'), or just stop usng LIKE, if you don't really need it.
It may run faster on your system due to better specs or/and less load.